# Which values are possible for the javaMail SMTP session property mail.smtp.ssl.protocols?

Tags: java, ssl

I am searching for nearly an hour so far to find a specification or list for valid values to fill this property.

I am using the javax.mail.Session and invoke the Session.getInstance(props) to set "mail.smtp.ssl.protocols".

I have an example in the code, i am working on: "TLSv1". I want to know, if there are more versions for TLS available or if i can leave the version out and just set it to "TLS" instead.

The hints and links i followed on the web, were not concrete enough or were dead links.

Where I searched yet so far:

- https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19159-01/819-3672/beaoz/index.html
- www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html (seems to point to a specification at Link "SMTP", but following it there is an empty page)
- https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/Session.html#getInstance-java.util.Properties- (mentions an appendix A for a list of properties, but i didn't find such a list, just an eBook to buy)

Many links to Oracle documentation only show the Oracle landing page.
Wikipedia description for SMTP mentions the RFC 821, but it does not contain a list of properties or a link to them.

Thank you for help.

Comment: as far as i know we no need to use "mail.smtp.ssl.protocols" to send a mail. java will take care of it.

Comment: The Javadoc clearly states 'The property value is a whitespace separated list of tokens acceptable to the javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket.setEnabledProtocols method.'

Comment: @Soorapadman: but I would like to prevent SSLv2 and SSLv3. So i thought, i should set TLS here.

Comment: @EJP: yes, I thought this would lead me to a definition. But I didn't see one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

SSLSocket provides a method `getSupportedProtocols()`:

`SSLSocketFactory sf = new SSLSocketFactoryImpl();
SSLSocket s = (SSLSocket) sf.createSocket();
System.out.println( Arrays.toString( s.getSupportedProtocols() )) ;`

**Output:**   [SSLv2Hello, SSLv3, TLSv1, TLSv1.1, TLSv1.2]

http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLSocket.html#getSupportedProtocols%28%29

**Details:**

https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/com/sun/mail/smtp/package-summary.html

> mail.smtp.ssl.protocols - Specifies the SSL protocols that will be enabled for SSL connections. The property value is a whitespace separated list of tokens acceptable to the javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket.setEnabledProtocols method.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLSocket.html#setEnabledProtocols%28java.lang.String[]%29

> The protocols must have been listed by getSupportedProtocols() as being supported.

Comment: I understood, that these supported protocols first have to be set somewhere. The last link shows "We're sorry, the page you requested was not found."

Comment: Thanks. I tried out, but just got "Type 'sun/security/ssl/SSLSocketFactoryImpl' (current frame, stack[0]) is not assignable to 'javax/net/ssl/SSLSocketFactory'".